# Possible to snap a metro-style app to exactly half the screen size in Windows 8 Release Preview?

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to snap a metro-style app to **exactly** half the screen size in Windows 8 Release Preview?

On a desktop/laptop where screen size is 1920x1080 or 2560x1440, can metro apps be resized/snapped next to "desktop-app" exactly half the screen size, via registry or any other hack... as it can come extremely handy while watching TV/video.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It is fixed but maybe we can expand the question about finding a unofficial way to snap half screen. I would love this ability!

Answer (score 3):

No, It is limited to 320px regardless of overall screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

No. All the views (snapped, filled, full) are fixed.

Response to related (not same) question in [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/eb103757-6a74-41e8-9bf2-fd24262ccec3) about tweaking the screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The snap size is fixed, i.e is 320 pixels wide.
However the Fill view is not fixed. Fill view is basically the FullScreenLandscape - 320 pixels(Snap view) - 20 pixels(Seperator)

Comment: Could you tweak the snap size in the registry or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

No, the size is fixed.

You have to ensure that your app continue to work in both snapped and filled view.

Answer (score 0):

@LZH
what do you mean by the size is fixed?
obviously it's not fixed. I can support different resolutions.
So while I change resolution size of my screen the snap view size is fixed(i.e 320 pixels).
Remaining is the fill view.. So obviously fill view size is not fixed.

have a look at this link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx
Please read the note.
It says fill view is 1024 relative pixels wide or greater..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx
This link give you all the screen sizes for which Snap and Fill View exists!